# C++: operator << implicit cast priority

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

In the next example, why the `operator <<` prefer to cast to double rather than to string? Is it because primitive have higher priority?

```
class R {
public:
    R(double x) : _x(x) {}
    operator string () {cout << "In string operator\n"; return std::to_string(_x);}
    operator double () {cout << "In double operator\n"; return _x;}
private:
    double _x;
};

int main() {
    R r(2.5);
    cout << r << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `operator std::string()` simply isn't viable. The `operator<<` overload taking `basic_string`s is

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>& os, const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& str);
```

And template argument deduction can't deduce the template arguments from the type `R`. It won't look through implicit conversions.

You can see this by commenting out `operator double` and [watching your code explode](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78d21a6e6c98c102).